# Is it possible to add Photo Album from Google Drive to Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I used Google Drive software to sync my computer data into Google Drive. As their additional features, I uploaded Photos also. Which now available in Google Drive-My Computer-My Photos. All these Photos are available in Google Photos also but not in form of the album. I want all my photos available under Google Drive->My Computer->My Photos as a album in Google Photos -> My Photos. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to know that we can not add a photo album from google drive to google photos directly. But it will sync all photos from the drive into the google photos. Then you can create one empty album into the Google Photos then add drive album photos into that.